# Why is $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\dfrac{1}{n+1}\right)^{n+1}=e$ trivial?

Tags: analysis

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\dfrac{1}{n+1}\right) ^{n+1} =e$$

Could someone explain me why this is trivial ? Maybe subsitution such that $n+1=m$ which would give us the definition of $e$ ?

Comment: The substitution works. Since $(1+1/n)^n$ converges to $e$, so does its every subsequence.

Comment: Exactly as you said!

Comment: @Wojowu thanks a lot. for a certain reason i also thought i had to subsitute the expression lim(−1)→∞ as with +1= would be n=−1 but this sounds not correct

Comment: "Maybe subsitution such that n+1=m which would give us the definition of e ?"  Yep.   ... welllll.... That would give you $\lim_{n\to \infty} (1 + \frac 1{n+1})^{\frac 1{n+1}} = \lim_{m-1\to \infty}(1+ \frac 1m)^{\frac 1m}$.  We have to proof or take it for granted that $\lim_{m\to\infty} a_m = \lim_{m-1\to \infty} a_m$... which.... it is...

Comment: @fleablood as this is linear substitution right?

Comment: "as this is linear substitution right?"  If I understand what you mean, I think so.  $\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n = c$ is by definition means for every $\epsilon > 0$ there is an $N$ so to that $n > N$ means $|a_n - c| < \epsilon$.  ANd as $n > N \iff n+1 > N+1$ substitution $N+1$ with $N$ we for all $n+1 > N+1$ then $|a_n - c| < \epsilon$ so $\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n = c \iff \lim_{n+1\to \infty} a_n$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let 
$$a_n = \left( 1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^n$$

Since this sequence converges to $e$, any subsequence of it also converges to $e$.

Set $k_n=n+1$. Then, the corresponding subsequence is 
$$a_{k_n}=\left(1+\dfrac{1}{n+1}\right) ^{n+1}$$
and hence it converges to $e$.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Recall that :

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left( 1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^n = e$$

So, any expression that can be substituted to this initial form, yields $e$.

For $m = n+1$ it is $m \to \infty$ when $n \to \infty$ and thus :

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left ( 1 + \frac{1}{n+1}\right)^{n+1} = \lim_{m \to \infty} \left ( 1 + \frac{1}{m}\right)^m = e$$

Comment: thanks a lot. for a certain reason i also thought i had to subsitute the expression $\lim_{(m-1) \to \infty}$  as with $n+1=m$ $n$ would be $m-1$ but this sounds not correct

Comment: @MathsGuy yeah in general, you would have to do that with your substitutions. However in this case, $m-1\to\infty$ is the same as $m\to\infty$ so the limit simplifies.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't say it's "trivial" but

1)  If $\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n = c$ then $\lim_{n\to \infty} a_{n+1} = \lim_{n\to \infty} a_n = c$.

This should be intuitively obvious but it can be formally proven: Pf:  For any $\epsilon > 0$ we can find an $N$ so that $n > N$ means $|a_n - c| < \epsilon$.  So if $n > N-1$ then $n+ 1 > n$ and $|a_{n+1} - c| < \epsilon$ so $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{n+1} = c$.

And 2) by *definition* $\lim_{n\to \infty} (1 +\frac 1n)^{\frac 1n} = e$ and so... $\lim_{n\to \infty} (1 +\frac 1n)^{\frac 1n} =\lim_{n\to \infty} (1 + \frac 1{n+1})^{\frac 1n } = e$

Answer (score 1):

The sequences

$$a_0,a_1,a_2,a_3, a_4,\cdots$$

and

$$a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4,\cdots$$

have the same limit.

Answer (score 0):

You have already figured it out by yourself! Actually enforcing the substitution $m=n+1$ leads to

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac1{n+1}\right)^{n+1}=\lim_{m\to\infty}\left(1+\frac1m\right)^m=e$$

which overall approves your observation.

Comment: thanks a lot. for a certain reason i also thought i had to subsitute the expression lim(−1)→∞ as with +1=  would be n=−1 but this sounds not correct

Comment: @MathsGuy Of course we have to be careful with expressions containing infinite expressions. But in this case we can simply argue, as *Rebellos* did within his answer, that while $n$ is approaching infinity $n+1$, i.e. our new variable $m$, is going towards infinity aswell hence a small minus one does not count that much in this particular context.

Comment: but when do i have to be carefull ? whats the rule ? i.e. $n^2$ converges also to infinity but used in a slightly different way would give us different answers

Comment: @MathsGuy What we are doing here is a linear substitution which does not change anything since both, $n$ and $an+b$, are growing in an equal speed. However, $n^2$ is not a linear function but a square which grows faster. I am not an expert on the field of function growth but I would claim that you can argue like this, i.e. by saying all linear functions grow at the same speed but slower than a quadratic or a cubic function.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Revise the definition of a limit. There is some threshold beyond which all values of $n$ give close enough values of the sequence at hand to the value of the limit (if it exists). Does it really matter what happens before that threshold? Can it be extended (*i.e.*, increased)?

*Hover over, click, or tap the box below for spoilers.*

> No. Yes.